# How to read status code from telnetlib python?

Tags: python

I'm writing a python script to verify emails existence, my code is:

```
import telnetlib
with telnetlib.Telnet('MXBIZ1.QQ.COM',25) as tn:
    tn.set_debuglevel(1)
    tn.write(b'HELO hello\r\n')
    tn.write(b'MAIL FROM saihhold.chiu@gmail.com\r\n')
    tn.write(b'RCPT TO zhaoshihao@mark.hk\r\n')
    tn.read_all()
```

it outputs like this:

```
Telnet(MXBIZ1.QQ.COM,25): send b'HELO hello\r\n'
Telnet(MXBIZ1.QQ.COM,25): send b'MAIL FROM saihhold.chiu@gmail.com\r\n'
Telnet(MXBIZ1.QQ.COM,25): send b'RCPT TO zhaoshihao@mark.hk\r\n'
Telnet(MXBIZ1.QQ.COM,25): recv b'220 bizmx45.qq.com MX QQ Mail Server\r\n'
Telnet(MXBIZ1.QQ.COM,25): recv b'250 bizmx45.qq.com\r\n'
Telnet(MXBIZ1.QQ.COM,25): recv b'250 Ok\r\n'
Telnet(MXBIZ1.QQ.COM,25): recv b'250 Ok\r\n'
```

My questions are:

1. I want it returns status code only like:250,220 etc. how can I do that?
2. I want to read response step by step, i tried to insert tn.read_all() in each command, but looks like something wrong.
   thanks.

---

this problem is resolved,
here is the code:

```
import telnetlib
import time

def sleep(duration):
    return(time.sleep(duration))

def read():
    return(str(tn.read_very_eager(),'utf-8'))

def write(str):
    return(tn.write(bytes(str+'\r\n','ascii')))

mail_list = ['xxx@example.com']
v_list = []

with telnetlib.Telnet('MX.EXAMPLE.COM',25) as tn:
    tn.set_debuglevel(1)
    sleep(2)
    write('HELO hello')
    sleep(2)
    write('MAIL FROM:<example@gmail.com>')
    sleep(2)
    for i in range(0,len(mail_list)):
        write('RCPT TO:<' + mail_list[i] +'>')
        sleep(2)
        rt_res = read()
        if '250' in rt_res:
            v_list.append(mail_list[i])
print(v_list)
```

Comment: What do you mean by "read response step by step"? From the log output it looks like there is no response until the last data has been sent.

Comment: means one input one output, now you can see here are 3 inputs in beginning and 4 outputs in the end. the first 250 code is corresponding to the first input HELO hello.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the status codes, it looks like you can assign the return value of `read_all()` to a variable, then split it into a list of lines by calling the method `split(b'\r\n')`. Then split each line at whitespaces by using `split()` and take the first item of the resulting list by using list indexing `[0]`.

Comment: ok, but how can I get outputs in a correct sequence? now there are 3 inputs in beginning and 4 outputs after those, the first 250 code is corresponding to HELO , the second one is corresponding to MAIL FROM and the third is to RCPT TO...